# Problema com cloudfront aws com Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, amazon-aws

estou com um problema que não faço a minima ideia de como resolver.

Estou hospedando um site feito com vue e nuxt no cloudfront da aws, até ai tudo normal

Quando estou em alguma página interna e recarrego apertando F5, ele buga, quebra todos os componentes misturando componente da página principal com a págia atual.

Isso não acontece quando subo no heroku e nem local.

Creio que o problema possa ser o Cloudfront.

Comment: Veja como está o código fonte, principalmente os css e js. Acredito que te possa te ajudar.

Comment: Gleidson, creio que o problema não esteja no css e nem no js e sim no CloudFront, esse é o link que está hospedado no heroku https://assinevivocontrole.herokuapp.com... Tudo está perfeito